# DevExpress XtraReport in a MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress, xtrareport

Maybe this is very simple, but I just can't get it to work.
 Here's the thing:

1. I created a XSD schema and then drag and drop the table from my DataSource (SQL Server).
2. Now I can work in report designer, since I set the data source to the .xsd file, so I drag and drop fields onto the report surface. Everything fine.
3. I then have the controller which has an action that opens the razor view with report.

So far so good. In action, I just created the instance of one item from the database, and am setting that as a data source for the report, but when I show the view it never binds it. Nothing in the report, just labels and headers. I simply want to be able to pass an object of the type that I created and when I set the report source to be able to see data.
I don't want any parameters and filtering.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Review [this](http://help.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9974) help topic and ensure that you have performed all required steps correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `dataSource` and `dataMember` of the report at the code behind event `DataSourceDemanded` of the `XtraReport`.

The Data i'm passing is a `Datatable` object

```
Private Sub myReport_DataSourceDemanded(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.DataSourceDemanded

    Me.DataSource = session("myData")
    Me.DataMember = "movimentacao_creditos"


End Sub
```